# Express.JS + Node-Mysql and 1 connection per http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-mysql

I'm new to Express, and am trying to wrap my head around Express + Node-Mysql.

I want to use a new mysql connection for each http request.

Here is my app.js file:

```
var express = require( "express" ),
    mysql = require( "mysql" ),
    routes = require( "./routes" );

var app = module.exports = express(),
    db = mysql.createConnection( require( "./config/db" ) );

app.configure(function(){
    app.set( "views", __dirname + "/views" );
    app.set( "view engine", "jade" );
    app.set( "db", db );
    app.use( express.logger( "dev" ));
    app.use( express.bodyParser() );
    app.use( app.router );
    app.use( express.static( "front" ));
});

app.configure( "development", function(){
    app.use( express.errorHandler() );
});

routes( app );

app.listen(80);
```

Then, in my route files, I do something like the following:

```
module.exports = function( app ){

    var db = app.get( "db" );

    app.get( "/stuff", function( req, res ){

        db.connect( function(err){

            var sql = "SELECT * FROM stuff";

            db.query( sql, function( err, result ){

                res.send( result );
                db.end(function( err ){ });

            });

        });

    });

};
```

This works, but I am not sure if it is "proper".  Is there a cleaner way to accomplish what I am after?

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do one db connection per request, put this line:

```
db = mysql.createConnection(require( "./config/db" ));
```

inside your request handler (e.g. inside routes.js), right before where you do `db.connect()`. Call `db.end()` once you have gotten all the results from your queries.

Since connecting to the database is a relatively expensive operation though, you may want to consider using a connection pool. Keeping a few connections open and pulling a free connection out of the pool when you need it will be more efficient than opening and closing a new connection for each request. The [generic-pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool) [npm module](http://npm.im/generic-pool) is a good one.