# Safely keeping MySQL connections alive

Tags: mysql, connection-timeout

I'm working on a node.js application that connects to a MySQL server.  The following likely isn't node.js-specific, though.

Currently, my code initializes a MySQL connection at the application start-up, and then it uses that connection every time it needs to make a query.

The issue I'm facing with my approach is that the connection tends to close after a period of time.  I'm not sure how long that period of time is, but it seems to be at least several hours.  I'm also not sure whether it's caused by inactivity.

In any case, I'm wondering what would be a better approach for managing MySQL connections long-term.  Of possible approaches, I've considered:

- Simply checking before each query to see whether the connection is still valid.  If not, reconnect before executing the query.
- Pooling MySQL connections.  Would this be overkill for a fairly small application?
- Periodically (every hour or so), execute a query, in case this is occurring due to inactivity.  However, this doesn't remedy the situation in possible cases not caused by inactivity.
- Connect and disconnect before/after queries.  Bad idea because of the overhead involved.

I'm leaning toward using one of the first two options, as you might imagine.  Which of the options would be most reliable and efficient?

Comment: Pooling is *not* "overkill". Use it. Someone else wrote it (hooray! there are several node implementations), and it Just Works without needing to worry about actual connection management (e.g. "keeping connections alive") other than "releasing to pool".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practice for Node.js seems to be to use a connection pool. See [Node.js MySQL Needing Persistent Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015590/node-js-mysql-needing-persistent-connection).

The default timeout for idle connections is 28800 seconds, and is configurable with the `wait_timeout` variable. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Comment: Thanks!  Pooling it is.

Comment: how to achieve this  for a Django powered application  ?  Any idea ?

Comment: @farzi_engineer, Scroll to the top of this page. See the field with the word "Search..." Type **django connection pool** into the field. Press return. A number of past questions about Django and connection pools appear. Read them.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*----------
  @brief
In this code, const connectionsToPing = Math.floor(pool._freeConnections.length / 2) calculates the number of connections to ping as half of the available free connections.

By distributing the pings in this way, subsequent intervals will ping the remaining connections in the second half of _freeConnections , achieving a balanced distribution of keepalive pings over time.

This modification ensures that only a portion of the free connections are used for keepalive pings, preventing the exhaustion of all available connections in a single interval.
*/

const mysql = require("mysql");

// Create a MySQL connection pool
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "your_database",
  connectionLimit: 10 // Adjust the connection limit as per your need
});

// Function to send keepalives to a portion of connections in the pool
function sendKeepalives() {
  if (pool._freeConnections.length === 0) {
    console.log("No free connections available to send keepalives.");
    return;
  }//if

  const connectionsToPing = Math.floor(pool._freeConnections.length / 2);

  for (let i = 0; i < connectionsToPing; i++) {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error getting connection from pool:", err);
        return;
      }

      connection.ping(err => {
        connection.release();
        if (err) {
          console.error("Error sending keepalive:", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Keepalive sent successfully");
        }
      });
    });
  }//for
}//fn

// Schedule keepalives every 30 seconds
setInterval(sendKeepalives, 30000);

// You can now use the pool to execute queries or tasks
pool.query("SELECT * FROM your_table", (err, results) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Error executing query:", err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(results);
});

//end
```