# In nodejs with MySQL

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native, node-mysql

I am Using Nodejs with MySQL.

But problem is that My MYSQL Connection Password Able to see in browser, With this any user get my my SQL username and Password.

Is it possible no one can see my MySQL Connection permanent as its is a server side.

Can any one help me in this.

Comment: Add in some code.. or the URL to the web page that you are developing..

Answer (score 1):

Do not send you password to client but store it in a variable inside your server-side script. On a request, use it to access database and send only the result of the operation.

*If you show your code you might get a more detailed answer then this...*

Answer (score 0):

```
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'host',
   user     : 'dbuser',
   password : "pword",
   database : 'database',
 });

 connection.connect();

 connection.query(etc etc etc)
```

for full example see [mysql module in node.js not works in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891513/mysql-module-in-node-js-not-works-in-my-case?rq=1)

or another way is to save the configuration and password details in either an env file or other file (or even sqlite db file and load it on startup/restart of your script