# Node.js response from http request not calling 'end' event without including 'data' event

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, events

So I have a simple client application communicating with a server side application in node.js. On the client side, I have the following code:

```
function send (name) {
    http.request({
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3000,
        url: '/',
        method: 'POST'
    }, function (response) {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function (data) {
           console.log('did get data: ' + data);
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log('\n   \033[90m request complete!\033[39m');
            process.stdout.write('\n your name: ');
        });
        response.on('error', function (error) {
            console.log('\n Error received: ' + error);
        });
    }).end(query.stringify({ name: name})); //This posts the data to the request
}
```

The odd part is, if I don't include the 'data' event via:

```
    response.on('data', function (data) {
       console.log('did get data: ' + data);
    });
```

The 'end' event for the response is never fired off.

The server code is as follows:

```
var query = require('querystring');
require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
    var body = '';
    request.on('data', function (data) {
       body += data;
    });
    request.on('end', function () {
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end('Done');
        console.log('\n got name \033[90m' + query.parse(body).name + '\033[39m\n');
    });
}).listen(3000);
```

I would like to know why this is happening when the documentation (to my knowledge) doesn't require you to listen in on the data event in order to close a response session.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `'end'` is invoked only when all the data was consumed, check the reference below:

> Event: 'end'
>
> This event fires when no more data will be provided.
>
> Note that the end event will not fire unless the data is completely
>   consumed. This can be done by switching into flowing mode, or by
>   calling read() repeatedly until you get to the end.

But why you need to call the `.on('data',..)`?  The answer is

> If you attach a data event listener, then it will switch the stream
>   into flowing mode, and data will be passed to your handler as soon as
>   it is available.

So basically by adding the `data` listener, it changes the stream into flowing mode and starts consuming the data.

Please check [this link](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) for more reference about it.

Comment: Thank you for that tid bit of information. I didn't have a full understanding of what 'flowing mode' meant, so this is a great explanation. It's a bit weird IMO because you'd expect it to still fire the data event followed by the end event, but I guess there a pause in the stream flow at that point that must keep state without pushing forward. I was looking through some books published for node.js about a year ago and this is no where to be found, so maybe it's new?

Comment: I also have to say I had to seriously dig down from the http documentation to find this. That documentation is seriously hidden and should be emphasized better.

Comment: @TheGamingArt yeah I had to dig a lot to find this info, at the first beginning I thought it was a bug in your code :)

Comment: I have the `.on('data')` but the `.on('end')` never starts

Comment: @bubakazouba please post a new question about it with more details and the code

Comment: i did post a new question