# res.end() does not work with jquery post request

Tags: jquery, node.js

Why does res.end('Sent') not work even though the console.log runs? I believe it is because of the way the post request got sent but I really have no clue as to why.

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function post() {
  $.post("/", {
    type: "foo"
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body><button onclick="post()">Post</button></body>
</html>
```

### NodeJS

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        console.log('foo');
        res.end('Sent');
    } else {
        res.end(index);
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js response from http request not calling 'end' event without including 'data' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817180/node-js-response-from-http-request-not-calling-end-event-without-including-da)

Comment: what exactly do you mean it doesn't work? your ajax request isn't accepting a response, so... other than a request being sent, nothing should happen visually on the page.

Comment: @KevinB If you run the code and click the button it prints 'foo' to the terminal but res.end('Sent') doesn't reload the page to read 'Sent'

Comment: it isn't supposed to reload the page, that's how ajax works.

Comment: @KevinB then how would I modify the page server side and send it to the client?

Comment: you would send text back to the client and receive it via a callback to $.post, or, you would use an html `<form>` instead of ajax.

Answer (score 0):

An ajax request from the browser just sends a request to the server and retrieves a response.  By itself, an ajax response has nothing to do with the page that is showing in the browser.  If you want to do something with the ajax response in the browser, then you have to write some Javascript to handle the response and then do something with it.

At the bare minimum, you could write something to the console just to see what response you got.

```
<script>
function post() {
  $.post("/", {type: "foo"}).then(function(data) {
    // handle response here
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

If you want that content to show in the current browser window, you could also write some Javascript to insert that content into the current page:

```
<script>
function post() {
  $.post("/", {type: "foo"}).then(function(data) {
    // replace current page contents with the data we got back
    document.body.innerHTML = data;
  });
}
```

---

If you create a form in your HTML page and set it up with an action URL and POST as the method and let the browser submit the form automatically, then the browser will take whatever response it gets from the server and automatically replace the contents of the current page with that response.  But, that is only if the form is submitted by the browser itself, not via an Ajax call from your own Javascript.  Ajax calls don't, by themselves, influence the current page contents.  Any change to the current page from an Ajax call has to be done by your own Javascript.